# Проблема с капчей

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться, почему в [этой](http://spravka-bataysk.ru/userreg.php) форме при нажатии на картинку с капчей (для загрузки новой картинки) выдает:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/spravkab/public_html/useradd.php on line 66? Причем выдает при заполненной форме, а при чистой все работает нормально.

```
<?
session_start();

//echo $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'];

include("config.php");

$dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");

$name = $_POST["nameshort"];
$fullname = $_POST["namefull"];
$orgform = $_POST["type"];
$phones = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["phone"]);
$faxes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fax"]);
$add_phones = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["morephones"]);
$address = $_POST["address"];
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["category"]);
$efforts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Comments"]);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
$website = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["site"]);
$skype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["skype"]);
$icq = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["icq"]);

$lon = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lon"]);
$lat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lat"]);
$mapp = $_POST["mapp"];
$refresh = $_POST["refresh"];

$URL="index.php";

$accept = 1;
if ($refresh == '1') {
    $URL = "userreg.php?r=1&nameshort=$name&namefull=$fullname&type=$orgform&phone=$phones&fax=$faxes&morephones=$add_phones&address=$address&category=$category&Comments=$efforts&email=$email&site=$website&skype=$skype&icq=$icq&lon=$lon&lat=$lat&mapp=$mapp";
    $accept = 0;
} elseif (($name == '') or ($fullname == '') or ($orgform = '') or ($phones == '') or ($address == '')) {
    $URL = "userreg.php?nameshort=$name&namefull=$fullname&type=$orgform&phone=$phones&fax=$faxes&morephones=$add_phones&address=$address&category=$category&Comments=$efforts&email=$email&site=$website&skype=$skype&icq=$icq&lon=$lon&lat=$lat&mapp=$mapp";
    $accept = 0;
} elseif(isset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']) && $_SESSION['captcha_keystring'] !== $_POST['captcha']){
    $URL = "userreg.php?e=1&nameshort=$name&namefull=$fullname&type=$orgform&phone=$phones&fax=$faxes&morephones=$add_phones&address=$address&category=$category&Comments=$efforts&email=$email&site=$website&skype=$skype&icq=$icq&lon=$lon&lat=$lat&mapp=$mapp";
    $accept = 0;
} elseif(preg_match('/http:\/\//', $address)) { // spam protection
    $accept = 0;
} elseif(preg_match('/http:\/\//', $efforts)) { // spam protection
    $accept = 0;
}
unset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']);

$sort_name = preg_replace("/^[«\'\"“]/", "", $name);

if ($mapp != 'on') {
    $lon='';
    $lat='';
}

$pattern = '/"([^a-zA-Z].*)"/';
$replacement = '«$1»';
while (preg_match($pattern, $name)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $fullname)) {
    $fullname = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fullname);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $address)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $address);
}

$pattern = '/»»/';
$replacement = '»';
while (preg_match($pattern, $name)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $fullname)) {
    $fullname = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fullname);
}


$website = preg_replace("/^http:\/\//", "", $website);
$website = preg_replace("/\/$/", "", $website);

$query = "INSERT INTO `wp_organisations` (`o_name`, `o_fullname`, `o_orgform`, `o_phones`, ".
            "`o_faxes`, `o_add_phones`, `o_address`, `o_category`, `o_email`, `o_website`, `o_skype`, ".
            "`o_icq`, `o_efforts`, `lon`, `lat`, `pending`, `created`, `sort_name`) VALUES ".
            "('$name', '$fullname', '$orgform', '$phones', '$faxes', '$add_phones', '$address', ".
            "'$category', '$email', '$website', '$skype', '$icq', '$efforts', '$lon', '$lat', '1', NOW(), '$sort_name')";

//echo ($query);
if ($accept) {
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}

mysql_close($dbh);
header ("Location: $URL");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Данная ошибка в этом коде может быть только в нутри цикла `while`. Чтобы определить, в каком цикле ошибка, можно использовать `exit();`.
В этом фрагменте кода через каждый цикл ставте функцию `exit()`. Например

```
while (preg_match($pattern, $name)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
}exit('Ок');
while (preg_match($pattern, $fullname)) {
    $fullname = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fullname);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $address)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $address);
}

$pattern = '/»»/';
$replacement = '»';
while (preg_match($pattern, $name)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $fullname)) {
    $fullname = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fullname);
}
```

Если вывело сообщение ОК, при этом грузилось не долго, то переносите функцию в конец следующего цикла. Если сообщение не выдаст, то можно понять где ошибка. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Ну так как исходники серверной части вашего скрипта недоступны для простых смертных, то вряд ли кто сможет сказать почему именно. Судя по всему, одно или несколько значений полей проходят валидацию в `useradd.php`, и, если они не пустые, то происходит их обработка. Как-то так. Ну а там, скорее всего, с этими данными происходит что-то вроде цикла (ошибочного или бесконечного, не буду гадать, скрипта самого ведь не видно). Поэтому происходит выброс ошибки `Maximum execution time` в 30 секунд, так как это превентивная мера в настройках самого `PHP`. Грубо говоря, тут надо рассматривать две вещи: либо бесконечный цикл (`loop`), либо `timeout` от какой-нибудь сторонней-встроенной функции, проверяющей данные (и, судя по всему, ей передаются данные, когда значение полей не пустые).

Дополнение:

```
$pattern = '/"([^a-zA-Z].*)"/';
$replacement = '«$1»';
while (preg_match($pattern, $name)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $name);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $fullname)) {
    $fullname = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $fullname);
}
while (preg_match($pattern, $address)) {
    $name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $address);
}
```

Строчка 66, я так полагаю, это последняя?

```
$name = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $address);
```

И вопрос: там точно `$name=` должно быть? Или `$address`?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Comment: По моему, было проще сказать "Чувак, у тебя косяк в каком-то цикле".

Comment: Заменил на адресс, теперь все нормально перегружает, только форма почему то пустая приходит?..

Comment: Ну я бы посоветовал бы сейчас повставлять echo/print для каждой "сомнительной" переменной "от строчки до строчки", либо debug запустить, чтобы видеть, какое значение присваивается каждой переменной при прохождении скрипта. Со стороны трудно мне это сделать, так как остальной движок на вашем сервере, а не на моем.

Comment: Заметил такую особенность - виснет только на адресе и только где есть кавычки (корпус "б", напр.), может здесь ключ?

Comment: Попытайтесь в самом начале скрипта (это всего лишь для отладки конечно) заменить без предварительных условий знаки "«» на строки, к примеру, XXXXX и т.д., а потом возвращайте обратно. По крайней мере это займет 5 минут, но даст возможность сконцентрировать область проблемы.
Честно говоря, мне с самого начала комбинация «» подозрительно не нравилась.

Comment: Чего-то я вообще не понимаю... Теперь ошибку выдавать перестало, нормально перегружается при нажатии на капчу. Только вот везде где есть кавычки, заменяет символы на слеши, а форма приходит вообще пустая!.. Я вообще не программер, я всего лишь дизайнер, это не мой скрипт. Я предлагаю просто исправить ошибки за плату, разумную, если есть такое желание.